# React: Cannot update object property in state in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, react-functional-component

**Problem I'm trying to solve:** Form validation for an app built in React that takes in user input and generates a CV. This is for learning purposes and part of The Odin Project curriculum.

**How I'm trying to solve form validation:** I have my project organized with a large formData object set as state in App.js and I'm sharing that state to all child components via useContext.
For validation, I have given each piece of CV data 2 properties in my formData object. Example below:

`{firstname: '', firstNameValid: true}`

I am trying to write a function (see attached code) that sets the validity of each propertyValid and set it to false.

**What I expect:** When a field is invalid (like firstName), it sets `firstNameValid: false` when I run the `invalidateField('firstName')` function.

**What happens instead:** Logging the formData reveals that `firstNameValid` is still set to `true`.

**What I have tried:** As seen in the attatched code, I am trying to make a copy of my formData object, set only the value I want, and then just manually set it using `setFormData(formCopy)`. However, when I log them together, I see that while formCopy looks like what I want it to be, the formData in state still has not changed. I am updating state just fine from my grandchildren components, but I'm unable to do it here and I don't understand why.

```
//my object declared in state
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    firstNameValid: true,
    lastNameValid: true,
    emailValid: true
    //a lot more than this but you get the idea
  });

//function in question that is not working
  function invalidateField(string){
    //takes the name of the key as a string
    let key = `${string}Valid`;
    let value = false;
    let formCopy = {...formData};
    formCopy[key] = value;
    
    setFormData(formCopy);
    console.log(formCopy, formData);
  }

//function I'm writing to check validity of input fields
//called by button click elsewhere in code
  function formIsValid(formData){
    let validity = true;
    if(formData.firstName.length < 1){     //firstName = '' (field is empty)
      console.log('your first name is too short');
      invalidateField('firstName');
      validity = false;
    }
    return validity;
  }


//context then passed to child components in the return statement.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I saw this post when first researching my question, and it didn't really help. I am updating state with very similar methods in my child components, and the changes are always reflected immediately. 
I'm very new to React so I don't fully understand what they mean by closures, but I don't think it applies to this situation.

Comment: Using `console.log` after updating the state will still show the old value. If you want to see the new value add the `console.log` in the body of the component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setFormData method is an async function. It takes a while until the state is updated. You console.log right after calling setFormData, thats why it looks as if your setState didnt work properly when it just needs a little more time to complete.

Above your invalidateField function you could write an useEffect to print out when your state has changed:

```
 import { useEffect } from "react";
    
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(formData);
    }, [formData]);
```

This will execute the console.log as soon as formData has changed.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see if it works. I didn't realize that ALL setState functions were async.

Comment: Okay yes thank you. That useEffect worked as intended and turns out my code was functioning exactly as intended the whole time. But thank you, this was a valuable lesson in how setState functions work.